# Elasticsearch-1.6.2 up-gradation

Tags: elasticsearch

We have updated elasticsearch-1.5.2 to elasticsearch-1.6.2.When trying to search data on the basis of "Rawlog_hash", still data is available for that particular "Rawlog_hash", no value is getting.But the same is working in 1.5.2 version.Please suggest.

Here is my query

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.2.1.51:9210/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "rawlog_hash": [
                  1118341815555609300,
                  5619467649792631000
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

output

```
{
  "took": 40,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 15,
    "successful": 15,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of `rawlog_hash`? Query seems to be fine.

Comment: @ChintanShah..I didn't get what you mean for mapping.The same query is working fine for elasticsearch-1.5.2 and not working for elasticsearch-1.6.2.